Blazor .NET 8 LINQ vs Async Function
Which one is better to use and why?
ApplicationUser? user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
ApplicationUser? userOne = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Single();

Return a ApplicationUser using an ID in Blazor .NET 8


If under _userManager is EF, FindByIdAsync can return User entity which already tracked without accessing database.

Second one is always accessing database in synhcronous manner, it means that thread which executes this query is blocked until query finished, it is bad for .NET server with high throughtput. Use SingeAsync or better FirstAsync instead. async-vs-sync

Same behaviour as first case you can achieve using FindAsync directly from DbSet: await _userManager.Users.FindAsync(userId);



ApplicationUser? user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
ApplicationUser? userOne = await _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId).SingleAsync();
So the difference between first and second line is that line one might not access database since one might be already tracked? Whereas line two will always access the Database?

Yes, i'm not sure what is under _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId), but if it is use EF Core's FindAsync under hood, difference is how often database is accessed.
